# How to adjust percentages of whole after increasing others

Tags: excel, math, percentage

How to redistribute %'s of a whole? Say i have 5 percentages (8%,21%,19%,40%,12%) and want to increase 8% and 21% to both be 25%, how would i adjust the remaining 3 percentages to fit this change? I am trying to do this in excel but can't figure out the formula.

Comment: So initially 19%,40% and 12% together constituted 71%. And now you want them to occupy just 50%. So you could do a (19%*50%*)/71%  , (40%*50%*)/71 and (12%*50%*)/71

Answer (score 0):

Put your initial values in **A1** through **A5**.  Put 25% in **B1** and **B2**.  In **B3** enter:

```
=A3*(1-SUM(B$1:B$2))/SUM($A$3:$A$5)
```

and copy downward.

[image]